# OP has edited my answer substantially

Tags: support, answers, edits

I'm not averse to the concept of others improving my answers. However an answer I provided to a question has been edited and the edit's don't sit well for me because they aren't really what I would consider as solutions:

> [ASP.NET - TTL on Session Key-Value-Pairs (InProc)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6024248/revisions)

The bit that bothers me is the edit at the end:

> **You may consider doing the following:**
>
> Maintain an active session for each
>   user:
>
> - Session("PersistMe") = true
>
> Grab SessionID, and use it to store
>   values in the ASP.NET Cache where you
>   may utilize a TTL value.

They're a bit vague and to be honest they're the OP's idea of possible solutions, not mine.

Would it be ok to move these up to the original question? I guess I'm trying to be as tactful as possible here as I think the edit was with good intentions judging by his/her past activity.

Comment: Diplomacy is a continuation of war by other means. (Zhou En Lai - Chinese diplomat )

Comment: @wether - indeed...question edited to remove all doubt as to my intent :)

Answer (score 10):

That does look like a bit of a different answer, which means it's not appropriate being added to yours  (except by you, or if it's Community Wiki).  I would remove that part, and respond to the OP suggesting they post it as an answer.  They may not have understood that **they can answer their own question**.

Let them know they may even get some votes for it, too.

In general, I'm open to anyone editing my question or answer, but as soon as it's not what I meant, or especially something I disagree with, I tend to think it's more appropriate that they post their own answer.

Answer (score 5):

This edit does seem over the top, I would have made the additions a comment on your answer (maybe even a separate answer, I don't know the subject matter so I can't tell how important they are). I don't think it's unacceptable behavior, unless he makes a habit of doing that.

A proper response would be to revert the edit, and leave a comment on your answer telling the editor you didn't like his changes and suggest reposting them under his name. Note that `@name` in a comment on a post works to notify anyone who edited the post.

I have a **one-revert rule**: it's ok to (occasionally) make an edit the original author doesn't like, and it's ok for the author to revert (except edits for reason of moderation, e.g. to remove insults). If the editor insists and won't let you have your post the way you want it, you can get a moderator involved; a moderator can lock your answer to prevent edits (even by you), and if the user is significantly disruptive, a moderator can write him a stern letter or suspend him.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit that information out of your question and post a comment to ask the OP to include it as a separate answer. It doesn't sound like it belongs in the question at all.

If the user persists in editing your answer to re-add the information, you can flag the question (or your answer) for moderator attention and ask a moderator to intervene.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the fact that it was the OP of the question who modified your answer is irrelevant =)

If you don't believe that edits to your answer have improved your answer so it provides more value to someone asking the question that the OP asked, revert the changes. If they did add value, consider leaving them as is. If you feel that parts might make more sense being part of the question then move them to the question.

In this specific example, I'm not sure why the OP decided to add to your answer and it would make sense to move parts of what they added to the original question.